# Since Commons HttpClient project is now end of life. I want to migrate my code to httpcomponent .

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

How can I set the HostConfiguration on the  CloseableHttpClient object . earlier while using the commons httpclient i used to do

```
myHttpClient.getHostConfiguration().setHost( host, port, baseHttps )
```

what is its equivalent in  Apache HttpComponents project ?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the following code:

```
URI uri = new URI(myURIString);

HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

HttpRoute route = new HttpRoute(new HttpHost(host,uri.getPort(),uri.getScheme()));
```